# Merge a dataframe with a (longer) datetime Series

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I'm pretty new to pandas

I have a dataframe with elements indexed by datetime, which looks like this
(the index is created by converting the timestamp with matplotlib.dates.date2num(), so that is ready for plot)

```
print(dframe)

                 average                 timestamp  timeonly
time                                                        
737216.401736 -16.099705 2019-06-06 09:38:30+00:00  09:38:30
737216.418252 -16.227859 2019-06-06 10:02:17+00:00  10:02:17
737216.424514 -16.352612 2019-06-06 10:11:18+00:00  10:11:18

737251.487894 -16.244289 2019-07-11 11:42:34+00:00  11:42:34
737251.513264 -16.290352 2019-07-11 12:19:06+00:00  12:19:06
737251.537512 -16.187445 2019-07-11 12:54:01+00:00  12:54:01

737301.412986 -16.108561 2019-08-30 09:54:42+00:00  09:54:42
737301.490231 -16.002861 2019-08-30 11:45:56+00:00  11:45:56
737301.559421 -16.040390 2019-08-30 13:25:34+00:00  13:25:34

737315.409931 -16.165562 2019-09-13 09:50:18+00:00  09:50:18
737315.440903 -16.473076 2019-09-13 10:34:54+00:00  10:34:54

737385.592465 -16.042004 2019-11-22 14:13:09+00:00  14:13:09
```

For each date (only date, e.g. 2019-06-06, 2019-08-30,...) I want to create different subplots of 'average' vs time but the time axis must be shared, i.e. the same time-only x-axis must be used (let's say from 9:00 to 15:00).

Creating different plots for different dates is easy:

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen
n_dates = list(unique_everseen(dframe['timestamp'].dt.date))  # a list of all date-only entries
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(n_dates) // 2, 2, sharey='all', constrained_layout=True) # plots on two columns
for ax, date in zip(axes.ravel(), n_dates):
    ts = pd.Timestamp(date, tz='UTC').date()
    df_date = dframe[dframe['timestamp'].dt.date == ts]
    # plot
    df_date.plot(y='average', linestyle='-', marker='o', label=ts, ax=ax)
```

but this would create non-aligned time-axis, that is in each subplots the xaxis would start at a different time (depending on the time of the first entry of df_date).

The solution I have in mind is to create an intermediate dataframe with a 'timeonly' column ranging from 9:00 to 15:00, like this

```
# this goes in the for-cycle above
timeax = pd.Series(pd.timedelta_range('9:0:0', '15:0:0', freq='S'), name='timeonly').to_frame()
df_date_ext = df_date.merge(timeax, how='outer', on=['timeonly'])  # this fails!
# plot!
df_date_ext.plot(y='average', linestyle='-', marker='o', label=ts, ax=ax)
```

However, merging of timeax and df_date fails :
`ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and timedelta64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`.
The problem is that dframe['timeonly'] is an `object`. Trying to convert it with pd.Timestamp doesn't work.

I tried with concat as suggested but I can't figure out how to join the two dataframes properly, i.e. so that the final df have values only where its 'timeonly' coincide with the one in timeax and NaN otherwise.

```
timeax.set_index('timeonly', inplace=True)
pd.concat((df_date.set_index('timeonly'), timeax), join='outer', ignore_index=False)
```

Comment: Plotly is pretty good at handling date axes and supports interactive features like data hovering and box zooming. Here is their [guide](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#subplots-with-shared-xaxes) to create subplots with a shared x-axis.

Comment: very nice indeed. Unfortunately if I pass df_date['timeonly'] as x value it doesn't work as expected: it puts all the 'timeonly' values for each date one after the other on the xaxis, i.e. 9:00 - 10:00 - 11:00...and then again 9:00 -10:00 - 11:00 so that the plots are not stacked as I wish

Comment: ok it seems plotly doesn't like df_date['timeonly'] (which is of type object). It works by converting it to timedelta64 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207677/merge-dataframe-object-and-timedelta64/65208005#65208005